How to read all the arguments into a single variable in expect script, like $@ in a shell script?
I want to read multiple arguments which contain double-quotes into a single variable in an expect script. Through the set command I assign a single argument, but something like $@ we use in a shell script. Searched the net but couldn't find anything.
Would appreciate any help with this.
I tried a few things :
Since we use lindex to set a single argument
set var [lindex $argv 0]

Tried :
set var $argv
set var $argv[@]
set var [lindex $argv @]
set var $args


like this: set var [join $argv " "]?

How do you plan to use $var? This is valid: set var $argv -- argv is a list, so you're setting var to be a copy of that list. Beware that argv is global: if you're doing this in a proc you'll need global argv; set var $argv or set var $::argv

You can read about Tcl's builtin global variables at https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/tclvars.htm

I need to pass it ($var) as a single argument to another command in expect script. At present I used a workaround to achieve that, but that's not very efficient.

I can try what @sexpect suggested and see if it works.

@glenn, I wanted to run install command ("Development Tools") with the quotes on a remote server (w/ CentOS) without logging in. There were other commands also along with this to run on that server. Other commands didn't have any issue except this one.
I used expect script within the bash to achieve that at present.

@user1645254, I strongly suspect this is a shell quoting problem. Ask a new question to provide the details.

I tried to escape the quotes with back-slash, but that didn't work either. So now I have no idea how to achieve this.
